# Is there a less verbose way of navigating this Python nested data structure?

Tags: python, nested

Quite a basic question but I am still not very good at making my code more compact. Is there a less verbose way of navigating multiple nested dicts in a list than what I have currently got?

```
myset = set(())

for element in nested_list:
    for value in element.values():
        for item in value.items():
            myset.add(item)
```

As a follow up, does it really matter if it is overly verbose?

Example data:

```
nested_list = [{
    "2020/48": {
        "Paradise": "Meduza",
        "Positions": "Ariana Grande",
        "Therefore I Am": "Billie Eilish"
    }
}, {
    "2020/47": {
        "Therefore I Am": "Billie Eilish",
        "Positions": "Ariana Grande",
        "Paradise": "Meduza",
        "You Broke Me First": "Tate Mcrae"
    }
}]
```

Just for reference, it is top 100 song chart data with each element in the list being a different week.

Comment: Add sample data for `nested_list`

Comment: Why do you loop over `nested_list` if you never use `element`?  How can you get `item.values()` before computing `item` (in the enclosed loop)?  Where is `entry` defined? You might want to focus on getting this *right* before worrying about making it *compact*.

Comment: "does it really matter if it is overly verbose?" -- it matters if it is hard to read, since hard to read code is hard to debug or modify. Verbose code is harder to read. On the other hand, it is possible to err in the opposite direction. It is fun to write 1-liners in python, but complex 1-liners can be harder to read than slightly longer equivalent code.

Comment: @ScottHunter whoops! Fixed it

Comment: I think your code would do anything other than get all item from `value` to `myset`. Because set will truncate dupplicate

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't overly verbose; the nested loops are necessary to process a nested data structure. I think there are only two things that can possibly be cut out: the explicit call to `myset.add` can be done implicitly with a set comprehension or some other way of collecting values in a set, and the innermost loop can be replaced with some bulk operation which deals with the whole of `.items()` at once rather than each element from it individually.

Here are a few options. A set comprehension at least avoids several layers of indentation:

```py
result = {
    item
    for element in nested_list
    for value in element.values()
    for item in value.items()
}
```

You can use `set.union` with the argument unpacking operator, but this looks a bit ugly. Unfortunately `set.union` doesn't accept `value.items()` directly even though it is a [set-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views), but `set().union` works because only the "self" parameter needs to be a real set.

```py
result = set().union(*(
    value.items()
    for element in nested_list
    for value in element.values()
))
```

Or you can use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```py
from itertools import chain

result = set(chain.from_iterable(
    value.items()
    for element in nested_list
    for value in element.values()
))
```

And here's a bonus version with no loops, because every question like this deserves an unreadable one-line answer that should not actually be used:

```py
set().union(*map(dict.items, chain.from_iterable(map(dict.values, nested_list))))
```

Personally I prefer the set comprehension, since it's syntactically cleaner and it's more obvious what it does, even though it has one more loop.

Comment: Ah that is quite nice. I never knew you could do things like set comprehension. Is there a place where I can read more about this and other constructions like it?

Comment: If you search for "comprehension" in the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) or any other Python tutorial, you should find something.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious improvement would be the last inner loop, which you can condense to this:

```
for element in nested_list:
    for value in element.values():
        myset.update(value.items())
```

Instead of adding each element one by one, update the set with the dict items directly. Other than this, there are of course many ways to bend over backwards and make it shorter somehow, but that wouldn't necessarily *improve* the code.

Comment: set.update can take arbitrary iterables, no need to make it a set first

Comment: You're right, great! The documentation was a bit vague on that and I didn't try…

Comment: Also, `.items()` returns a set-like object anyway, as long as the dictionary values are hashable (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views)).

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to first flatten the data structure a bit with a dictionary comprehension:

```
week = {k:v for d in nested_list for k,v in d.items()}
```

Then e.g. `week["2020/48"]` will give you the inner dictionary for that week.
Given that, a set comprehension can now extract the data you want:

```
myset = {item for d in week.values() for item in d.items()}
```